# How to return value as time in php

Tags: php, function, time

my probable is time summing function return value as time.

```
function GetApprovedOt($connect,$emp_id,$passmonth)
  {
      $query01 ="SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `ot_hour` ) ) ) AS timeSum 
                 FROM otresquest
                 WHERE em_id = $emp_id AND  from_month LIKE '$passmonth%' AND overtime_status=6";
      $statement = $connect->prepare($query01);

      if($statement->execute())
      {  

        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row){

              $sum =$row["timeSum"];
              return $sum;
             }

       }
  }
```

my probable is above function return more than 24 hour time like `120:20:00` .but my probable is i can't be compare this value in if condition correctly .so i need format return value as time variable .how do i do it ?

**Note**

```
  function formatHours($time){
    $date = explode(':', $time);
    return ($date[0]*60*60)+($date[1]*60)+$date[2];
    }
```

above function variable convert to time.in my case i can't apply directly as  `formatHours(GetApprovedOt($connect,$row["emp_id"],$_GET["month"]))` because it get notice and warning as

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\admin\report05.php on line 321

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\admin\report05.php on line 321

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\admin\report05.php on line 321
```

how i manage this case?
**update**
GetApprovedOt function var_dump return as

```
string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "40:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(9) "100:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "50:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "80:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(8) "60:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" string(9) "250:00:00" NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" string(8) "30:00:00" NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL string(8) "90:00:00" string(8) "90:00:00" string(8) "90:00:00" string(8) "90:00:00" string(8) "90:00:00" string(8) "90:00:00" string(8) "90:00:00" NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

Comment: In what format you are storing date & time ?

Comment: you need to improve your function's logic because your `GetApprovedOt()` does not always return a value, your query might fail i.e: `$statement->execute` returns `false` or your query return an empty result

Comment: ot_hour store as time type in sql database

Comment: try  to var_dump() the result of `GetApprovedOt()`, make sure it return the correct format `hh:mm:ss` in every case

Comment: okay bro i will try .how do change function with fail run

Comment: Can you tell us the expected output?

Comment: @catcon 'GetApprovedOt()' some time return as  'hh:mm:ss' format but some case it return 'NULL' value

Comment: @catcon i update with my question with var_dump out put .how do change GetApprovedOt function accordingly

Comment: @catcon if i get the value without coming null value problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is `GetApprovedOt` function always not not return time value.you should change your function as below

```
function GetApprovedOt($connect,$emp_id,$passmonth)
{
    $query01 ="SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `ot_hour` ) ) ) AS timeSum 
               FROM otresquest
               WHERE em_id = $emp_id AND  from_month LIKE '$passmonth%' AND overtime_status=6";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query01);

    if($statement->execute())
    {  
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row){
            if ($row["timeSum"] != NULL) {
                $sum =$row["timeSum"];
                return $sum;
            } else {
                return '00:00:00';
            }
        }

     }

}
```

now you can pass as `formatHours(GetApprovedOt($connect,$row["emp_id"],$_GET["month"]))`